# Insert and Create data from data array with existing data

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I''m new to laravel and vue.js. Need help :)

I have 2 tables. The *purchase* and the *remittance*. In my project, I have already STORED some data to the purchase table. But the *remittance_id* has no data yet (unsigned null by default and data should be stored after update).

So, for example. I checked table row 1 and table row 2. ((2) [{…}, {…}, ob: Observer] array list)

And by clicking my GENERATE REMITTANCE BUTTON, It will show a MODAL. And I have to input 2 fields (sample_date and sample_no) and it will automatically update the *remittance_id*
ON SUBMIT, my purchase table the 2 selected rows will now have *updated remittance_id of 1(for example)*. my *remittance* table will now create *sample_date*, *sample_no* and *remittance_id(1)*

```
<vs-prompt
                  @accept="generateRemittance"
                  :is-valid="validDate"
                  :active.sync="popupRemit"
                  accept-text= "Generate" title="Generate" color="warning">
                  <div class="con-exemple-prompt">
                    Enter details to <b>continue</b>.
                    <div class="vx-col w-full mb-base">
                      <div class="vx-row mb-6">
                        <div class="vx-col sm:w-1/3 w-full">
                            <span>SAMPLE DATE:</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="vx-col sm:w-2/3 w-full">
                          <vs-input  name="sample_date" class="w-full" type="date" v-model="sample_date"/>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="vx-row mb-6">
                        <div class="vx-col sm:w-1/3 w-full">
                            <span>SAMPLE NO</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="vx-col sm:w-2/3 w-full">
                            <vs-input name="sample_no" class="w-full" v-model="sample_no"/>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </vs-prompt>
                <vs-button @click="addRemit" type="filled" color="primary" icon-pack="feather" icon="icon-download">GENERATE REMITTANCE</vs-button>
```

*my method*

```
methods: {

addRemit(){
  this.popupRemit = true
},
generateRemittance () {
  this.$nextTick().then(result => {
      if (result) {
        this.$vs.loading();
        axios
          .post("/api/my/sample/url/", this.form)

          .then(res => {
              this.$vs.loading.close();
              Fire.$emit('AfterSave');
          })
          .catch(error => {
              this.$vs.loading.close();
              this.$vs.notify({
                  title: "Error",
                  text: error.response.data.errors || error.response.data.message,
                  iconPack: "feather",
                  icon: "icon-alert-circle",
                  color: "danger"
              });
          });
      }else {
          this.$validator.reset()
          this.$validator.resume()
          console.log(this.$validator.errors);
          this.$vs.notify({
              title: "Error",
              text: this.$validator.errors,
              iconPack: "feather",
              icon: "icon-alert-circle",
              color: "danger"
          });
      }
  });
},
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `purchase` table `belongsTo` the `remittance` table, so you'll want to create the remittance model first and save the purchase model after, you can do this with a tap:

```
tap(Remittance::create($request->only(['sample_no', 'sample_date'])), function (Remittance $remittance) use ($purchase) {
    $remittance->purchase()->save($purchase);
});
```

Here `tap` is giving us access to the created `Remittance` model in the callback, where we're then saving the one-to-one relationship.